# How to update the svn cmd-line tool, possibly installed on multiple places ?

Tags: svn, osx-mountain-lion, xcode4.5, macports

I have installed from `XCode -> Preferences -> Downloads` the `Command Line Tools`. I thought I will get the latest version of command-line tools that I need.

1. I checked using `xcrun -find svn` :

   - I found a first **Subversion** on   `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/`
   - the version of this svn is **1.6.18 (r1303927)**.
2. Then I used `which svn` :

   - I found another **Subversion** on `/usr/bin/`
   - the version is svn, version **1.6.18 (r1303927)**.

What the f**k is going on ? Do I have two copies on my os x ? the same build & compiled the same day ? or is there a link ? how to make appear plz ?

I remember using `xcode-select`... to make my command-line use the versions on `/Applications/XCode.app/`. So there is definitely something wrong here !

On *Apache-Subversion* website, the recommended version is **1.7.7**. So I intend to update the svn I use. The best way (for me) to get the binary package on *Mac OS X*, is by using `MacPorts`.

I runned `port installed subversion svn` -> `None of the specified ports are installed.` !

If I install using *macports* the latest *svn*, I may a third one somewhere lost on my osx.

Please, this is not a technical problem because I can work perfectly with the old svn, but I need explanation. And my question is `What is going on ?`

ps: feel free to edit my post to fit the requirement of a good question on stackoverflow.

Comment: Use `ls -l /usr/bin/svn` to see if it's a symbolic link.  If not `ls -i` both files and see if the inode is the same.  If so then it's a hard link.

Comment: none of the svns is a symbolic link.

Comment: Do they have the same inode (`ls -i`)?

Comment: They also got different inode numbers.

Comment: Then they are separate binaries.  Perhaps Xcode copies some binaries into `/usr/bin`, I don't know.  I wouldn't worry about it either.

Comment: This is definitely what is happening. `which -a svn`shows the one in `/usr/bin/`. But how to update to the 1.7.7 ?! plz

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Install [macports](http://www.macports.org/), which will modify your `~/.profile` to include `/opt/local/bin` at the start of `$PATH` (you might have to log out and back in for this to take effect).

Then:

```
$ sudo port install subversion
```

After that, `which svn` should show:

```
/opt/local/bin/svn
```

Comment: **Macports** is already installed, in `~/.profile` I have :

`# MacPorts Installer addition on x:x:x:` 
`adding an appropriate PATH variable for use with MacPorts.`
`export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH`

Comment: NOTE: had to start new terminal session to make `svn` envoke the 1.8 instead of 1.6